# Can I create an initial CodeIgniter db migration from .sql?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, migration

I have a CodeIgniter application and I just learned about migrations. It sounds very useful and I would like to start using it. However I already have a rather complex database setup. Can someone suggest a reasonable way to create a reliable initial migration from my MYSQL .sql schema file?

It seems excessive to manually recreate the entire db with dbforge, but perhaps that's what I ought to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bit late reply, but I hacked a quick library that should generate the base migration file for you from your current DB. Its still beta, but works on my systems 40 tables+

https://github.com/liaan/codeigniter_migration_base_generation

L:

Comment: It is great, but has one big issue, and that is it considers only the PK from keys, not (composite) unique nor FK.

Answer (score 1):

Visit https://github.com/fastworkx/ci_migrations_generator

You'll get something like this applications/migration/001_create_base.php.

```
public function up() {

    ## Create Table sis_customer
    $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
        'id' => array(
            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
            'constraint' => 40,
            'null' => FALSE,

        ),
        'ip_address' => array(
            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
            'constraint' => 45,
            'null' => FALSE,

        ),
        'timestamp' => array(
            'type' => 'INT',
            'unsigned' => TRUE,
            'null' => FALSE,
            'default' => '0',

        ),
        'data' => array(
            'type' => 'BLOB',
            'null' => FALSE,

        ),
        '`datetime_reg` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ',
    ));

    $this->dbforge->create_table("sessions", TRUE);
    $this->db->query('ALTER TABLE  `sessions` ENGINE = InnoDB');
    ));


public function down()  {

    ### Drop table sessions ##
    $this->dbforge->drop_table("sessions", TRUE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was messing around with SQL files manually and then I discovered Jamie Rumbelow's schema library. It makes schema operation a little bit easier to manage then DBForge but still requires manual entry.

https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-schema

Someone came up with a mashup of his base model and schema library and it makes prototyping much faster

https://github.com/williamknauss/schema_base_model_magic

this allows you to automate the CRUD model operations & schema

Comment: https://github.com/williamknauss/schema_base_model_magic 
It is broken, can anyone suggests the updated one?